# How to read file with lines of integers separated by a comma to a list without "\n"

Tags: python, file, operating-system

I am a new to the os module

I've been stuck for hours on this question and I really would appreciate any type of help:)

I have a file that contains 6 lines where each line has 6 numbers separated by a comma.
What I want to do is to get all of these numbers into a list so that I later can convert them from str to int. My problem is that I can't get rid of "\n".
[Here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPZqj.jpg)

Thank you

Comment: Show code and other textual information (input, output) as properly formatted text in the question, not as image or external link.

Comment: Please attach code that reproduces the issue, not an image or link

Comment: Does it have to be like this? Can you simply open the file and loop through the lines?

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def read_integers(path):
    content_lst=[]
    with open(path,'r') as file:
        content=file.read()
        for i in content.split('\n'):
            content_lst+=i.split(', ')
        return content_lst
```

Comment: this actually work, I will try to study it step for step, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your file actually has multiple lines (in addition to the comma separated numbers).  If you want all the numbers in a single "flat" list you'll need to process both line and comma separators.  One way to do it simply is to replace all the end of line characters with commas so that you can use split(',') on a single string:

```
with open(path,'r') as file:
    content_lst = file.read().replace("\n",", ").split(", ")
```

You could also do it the other way around and change the commas to end of lines.  Converting the values to integers can be done using the map function:

```
with open(path,'r') as file:
    content_lst = file.read().replace(",","\n").split()
    content_lst = list(map(int,content_lst))
```

Comment: this works too and is a bit more clearer, thank <3